# JMX server and JConsole cannot connect

Tags: java, jmx

I have a JMX enabled application which creates RMI Registry by doing:

```
rmiRegistry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(registryPort);
```

and then later on it creates [JMXConnectorServer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/remote/JMXConnectorServer.html) by doing:

```
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL(
      "service:jmx:rmi://localhost:" + serverPort 
      + "/jndi/rmi://:" + registryPort + "/jmxrmi");

connector = JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(
                    url, 
                    null,
                    ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer());
connector.start();
```

My problem is that I cannot connect to this JMX Server from a remote host using JConsole. I've followed the instructions for debugging/tracing JConsole and I can see that the problem is that JConsole tries to connect to a bogus IP address that it must have gotten from the Registry. Ok, it isn't exactly bogus because it happens to correspond to a virtual network interface I have on the JMX Server host machine. How on earth does JMX pick that up?

A `netstat` on my application reveals that both the `serverPort` and the `registryPort` are bound on the wildcard interface (on both IP4 and IP6) which is as expected since I haven't supplied socket factories. Basic connectivity works from the remote host, i.e. I can get the *telnet test* to pass on both ports.

I would have assumed that I would have to change 'localhost' in the `JMXServiceURL` to the name of my host (as other hosts sees it, not how it sees itself) but that doesn't help.

What do do ?

#### UPDATE1

After some more investigation I'm pretty sure this 'bogus IP address' comes because RMI just picks the first IP it finds on its own host and then uses that as its 'call-me-back' address. It then happens to find that virtual NIC that exists on this host. That's really not want I want. I want to be able to control explicitly the RMI 'call-me-back' address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to RMI hell.

The end point resolve himself and send back to jconsole the ip to use.

If you can try to use JMXMP : http://meteatamel.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/jmx-rmi-vs-jmxmp/.

You can also try java.rmi.server.hostname :
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/rmi/spec/rmi-properties2.html

Comment: Well, from reading those docs it seems difficult to control exactly what IP/hostname gets exported with your objects. I've tried using `java.rmi.server.hostname` but it only seems to have effect on what the documentation calls *out-of-the-box-setup* but mine is more of a DIY (Registry is created manually, connectorserver is created manually, etc).

Comment: I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167551/how-do-i-have-to-configure-a-rmi-environment-so-that-im-able-to-use-it-in-a-re) which is to some extent the same. The basic problem is that same, namely how to control the 'call-me-back' address that RMI uses. The accepted answer in that question is to fiddle with the hosts file. That's a no-go !

Comment: Any system property can be set within your code with System.setProperty(key, value). I use it frequently for java.awt.headless. But pay attention to set it before any class that use it is loaded.

Comment: Yep, setting `java.rmi.server.hostname` was the answer. I just did it incorrectly at first. Thanks.